# JetBrains Rider run with watch

Tags: c#, .net-core, watch, jetbrains-ide, rider

When I press run button in Rider (net core) it run the following command:

```
/usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet /pathtomyproject/myproject.dll
```

But I need to run the project with the argument "watch", if I write this command in Rider Edit Configurations's arguments I got error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: Unrecognized argument format: 'watch'.
```

I know to run with watch tool is `dotnet watch run`, and I know too that I can run that command in the terminal.

My question is if I can configure Rider to run this way when I press Run button? or... maybe Rider has an Edit and Continue feature that I don't know?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is an answer on Rider forum: https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360001346139-Simpler-integration-for-Microsoft-DotNet-Watcher-Tools

In short:

1. Open Run Configurations dialog
2. Add new "Before launch" configuration
3. Select "External tool"
4. Fill in "Tool settings" section (see the link above)

---

**Edit**

The external tool settings should be:

- *Program:* `c:\program files\dotnet\dotnet.exe`
- *Arguments:* `watch run`
- *Working directory:* `<path to your project folder>`

Comment: It would be nice to have an option to attach debugger to running `dotnet watch run` task. Now i'm switching between two configurations. Default one for debugging and second one for continuous building without debugging.

Comment: The link is no longer available

Comment: The link changed to: https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360001346139-Simpler-integration-for-Microsoft-DotNet-Watcher-Tools (I updated the answer with the new link)

Comment: For the working directory, you can use `$SolutionDir$$SolutionName$` to point to your startup project directory without hardcoding paths

Answer (score 5):

You can use the "Native Executable" option as a run configuration to make this happen. To do so:

1. Select Run -> Edit Configuration from the menu options
2. Click the + icon and select the "Native Executable" option from the list.
3. In the options that are displayed, provide the following...

   - Name: Watch (or whatever you prefer)
   - Exe path: /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet
   - Program Arguments: watch run
   - Working directory: [path to your project where .csproj file resides]
4. Click "OK" to apply/save the changes.
5. When ready, select Run -> Run... from the menu options. Select the "Watch" option.

You should see the terminal results build/run the app. If you change your controller file, you'll see the file change detected and the app rebuild.

Comment: I don't know what is your Rider version, but mine (latest) there is no Native Executable option. (macOS)

Comment: @YuriMorales I'm using 2018.3 (Mac) - Here's what I see in my Run/Debug Configurations that I built: https://www.evernote.com/l/ACI63LpG4vVKaYRtVjELVVKiKkf-xRS1d5c